# unix command 'zip' or 'compress' - file size is bigger than before

Tags: shell, unix, zip, compression, aix

I want to know unix shell command make this happen. 
when I use unix command zip or compress it makes file size bigger than before.
For example,
a.tar

```
$compress -f a.tar
> a.tar.Z
```

a.tar file size is 1131746050 
a.tat.Z file size is 1516269444

it was same in i use zip command.

i know compress command didn't work when file was bigger than before so I used -f option.
My question is why it was bigger?
I want to know reason about zip or compress command make more big file...

Comment: this might be able to explain it way better than I can: https://superuser.com/questions/467697/why-does-a-zip-file-appear-larger-than-the-source-file-especially-when-it-is-tex

Comment: You have your answer, but I should also mention that the _degree_ of expansion you're seeing (34%!) is due to the `compress` command itself. It is very badly behaved with already compressed data. `gzip` on the other hand will only expand compressed data by about 0.016%, or in your case adding only about 180K bytes to your 1 GB.

Comment: Before i did compress i did Encryption and tar command. I didn't do compress 'and' gzip double. I mean i want use compress 'OR' zip command.

Comment: Encrypted data is supposed to look like random bits. But random bits cannot be compressed, so you should compress first, encrypt afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may have already been compressed, or may just be a file that cannot be compressed any further. You can’t compress a file infinitely, or you’d just lose all the data. So if you try to compress them again, all it’s doing is adding compression data, and so the file actually gets larger.

Comment: I did 'tar' command but i didn't use -z option. hmm.. this file is Encryption file. Encryption file is make problem of this happened..?

Comment: Certain types of files just can’t be compressed. For example, plain text files cannot be compressed, as you would lose data from them. Sometimes it doesn’t matter as much if you lose some of the data, for example with images, they just lose a bit of quality. But you don’t want to lose any data from things like text files.